# How to add last element to list in for loop

Tags: c#

I am given a list of numbers and I need to find the largest sequence of increasing elements and print it out on the console. If there are 2 sequences with equal length then I should print the one that's first from the left.

This is what I tried:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Count - 1; i++)
{
    if (numbers[i] < numbers[i+1] && numbers[i] > 0)
    {
        counterFirstSequence++;
        firstSequence.Add(numbers[i]);
    }
}
```

However, because i only goes to `numbers.Count - 1` the very last element never gets added.

Comment: Well the last item is never going to be less than the next item, because there is no next item. How do you want to determine if you should add that one?

Comment: If last element is < than the previous it should be added. 
So for example: if the input is 7 3 5 8 -1 0 6 7 
Then the output should be: 3 5 6 7
But what I get is 3 5 6

Comment: So what I need to do is get the count of a sequence of numbers in increasing order.

Comment: `numbers[i+1]` would throw an `IndexOutOfRangeException` when `i == numbers.Count - 1`, so this doesn't work at all

Comment: Then you need an extra line to add that last item, because that is a different criterion than the one you use for all other items. If 7 has to be added in your example, it is > than the previous item, by the way. For all other elements you compare to `[i+1]`, for your last element you want an extra rule to compare to `[i-1]`.

Comment: Your specs are not very clear. What do you want to achieve? The example you gave in your comment should be part of the question, but it doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: Ok I wasn't very clear, I'll try to explain.
I am given a list of numbers and I need to find the largest sequence of increasing elements and print it out on the console. If there are 2 sequences with equal length then I should print the one that's first from the left.

Comment: @Nevion in the future, please edit the question to make it more clear instead of adding comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Count - 1; i++)
{
    if (numbers[i] <= 0) continue;
    if (numbers[i] >= numbers[i+1]) continue;

    counterFirstSequence++;
    firstSequence.Add(numbers[i]);

    //if the second to last element on the list meets the condition then the last 
    //element is also valid
    //for a zero based index, the second to last element would have the index 
    //numbers.Count - 2
    if(i == numbers.Count - 2)
    {
        counterFirstSequence++;
        firstSequence.Add(numbers[i + 1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This should give the result you want

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!